# Where to put $_Session[variable] in the code

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to save a variable in the $_Session[deptselect] and call it in a different page but confused to where to declare it. when i echo $_Session[deptselect] it gives blank.

I have already tried in multiple places like inside the form or below it but nothing seems to work. i want to send it from appointment to appointment2 but appointment2 seems to not get the variable.
I have already tried to use $_post[deptselect] to get the value in second page and i get it there but it disappears as soon as i press submit in the second page.

```
appointment.php

<?php
include("dbconnection.php");
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
  die("Please login");
}
$_SESSION['deptselect']=$_POST['deptselect'];
?>

<form class="" action="appointment2.php" method="post">  
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Appointment</legend>    
    <label>Select Department</label>
    <select class="" name="deptselect" required>
      <option ></option>
      <?php      
      $deptsql=mysqli_query($con,"select deptname,deptid from department where status='1'");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($deptsql))
      {
        echo "<option id='deptselect' value='" . $row['deptid'] ."'>" . $row['deptname'] ."</option>";
      }      
      ?>
    </select>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
include("footer.php");
?>
```

```
appointment2.php

<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
  include('footer.php');
  die("Please login");
}
if(!empty($_POST)){
  include("dbconnection.php");
  $dept=$_SESSION['deptselect'];
  echo $dept;
  $daate=$_POST['date'];
  $doc = $_POST['doc'];
  $tiime=$_POST['time'];
  $user=$_SESSION['username'];
  $pd="SELECT * from patient where name='$user'";
  $pid=mysqli_query($con,$pd);
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pid)){
    $piid=$row['pid'];
  }
  $query="insert into appointment (deptid, docempid,pid,apptime,appdate) VALUES ('$dept','$doc','$piid','$tiime','$daate') " ;
  //$res=mysqli_query($con,$query);
//  echo "$query";
  //echo "$dept";
}
?>
<body>
  <form class="" action="appointment2.php" method="post">
    <label>Select doctor</label>
    <select class="" name="doc" >
      <option ></option>
      <?php
      $dee=$_POST['deptselect'];
      $_SESSION['id']=$dee;
      $sql="SELECT * FROM doctor where  deptid='$dee'";
      $docsql= mysqli_query($con,$sql);
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($docsql))
      {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['docempid'] ."'>" . $row['name'] ."</option>";
      }
      ?>
    </select>
    <br><br><br>
    <label>Enter Time</label>
    <input type="time" name="time" placeholder="enter time" >

    <br><br><br>
    <label>Enter date</label>
    <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="enter date" >
    <br> <br>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

  </form>

</body>

<?php include("footer.php");
?>
```

I want the $_session[deptselect] in appointment2.php so i can run the command the insert, i have zero knowledge of js so doing the dependent list thing is not possible. TIA

Comment: where you storing the session variables ?

Comment: English only please.  Your apointment file sends the  `deptselect` value to the appointment2 file.  There is no need to write `$_SESSION['deptselect']=$_POST['deptselect'];` in the appointment file.  Based on what is posted, I don't see any need to store the deptselect value in the SESSION superglobal.

Comment: `<option>` tags don't get id attributes.

Comment: @mickmackusa is right you don't need to store in a `$_SESSION` to do cross PHP page data passing .. i think you should check the PHP manual [how to deal with forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) If you read that imagine the HTML form is in the `index.html` file.

Comment: It looks like appointment2 is POSTing form data to appointment2.  If you are worried about losing the `deptselect` value on that action, create a hidden input field and load the `deptselect` value into that.  You super need to implement prepared stayements for security and stability.  I've got to go with Too Broad on this one.  There are too many things to fix.  A complete rethink/refactor is in order.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of the first script you have:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    die("Please login");
}
```

And in the beginning of the second:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    include('footer.php');
    die("Please login");
}
```

Both stop immediately, if `$_SESSION['username']` is not set.
So how should `$_SESSION['username']` ever be set, if your *body* code is never executed?

Comment: And, even assuming it gets there in the code, `$_SESSION['deptselect']` is set in `appointment.php` but the form submits to `appointment2.php`.